# Search keyword in a file and find it's value in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a file "test.txt" with following contents:

```
TAG A    : HELLO 
DATE START   : Tue Oct 25 09:51:49 EDT 2015 
GIT BRANCH   : master 
GIT COMMIT   : fecb1b53ec8fffffffffffffffffffff09523c42
```

I have to find the value of "GIT BRANCH" from this file, which should be "master".

My logic to achieve this was to read this file line by line, match the keyword "GIT BRANCH" and find out it's value. 
I was able to read the file line by line and match the keyword but I don't know how to get it's value.

I am new to Clojure, any help to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is to keep it simple and map the file data. Then you can get the value of the key you're interested in from the map, in this case `"GIT BRANCH"`. By mapping the file data first, if you need to get other info like `"TAG A"` it will be easy.

```
(require [clojure.java.io :as io])
(def kv-re #"\s*(.*\S)\s*:\s+(.*\S)")  ;; regex to capture key and value
(def git-info
     (with-open [rdr (io/reader "test.txt")]
       (into {}
             (map #(vec (rest (re-find kv-re %)))  ;; map list of [k v]
                  (line-seq rdr)))))
```

Now you can pull the values from `git-info` as follows:

```
(get git-info "GIT BRANCH")  ;; -> "master"
(get git-info "TAG A")       ;; -> "HELLO"
(get git-info "TAG B")       ;; -> nil
(get git-info "TAG B" "foo") ;; -> "foo"
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, I wouldn't write code that specifically only works for this use-case. When you zoom out a little bit, you can just solve a more general version and possibly use that function in the future again.

Here is my version, you can get the final result with a simple `(get your-map "GIT BRANCH")`:

```
(def ff "
TAG A    : HELLO
DATE START   : Tue Oct 25 09:51:49 EDT 2015
GIT BRANCH   : master
GIT COMMIT   : fecb1b53ec8fffffffffffffffffffff09523c42 ")

(defn kv-parser
  [sep]
  (fn [s]
    (let [[k v] (mapv str/trim (str/split s sep))]
      (when (not-empty k)
        [k v]))))

(with-open [rdr (BufferedReader. (StringReader. ff))]
  (into {}
        (map (kv-parser #":"))
        (line-seq rdr)))

;; For reading a file you'd do:
(with-open [rdr (io/reader "./your-file")]
  (into {}
        (map (kv-parser #":"))
        (line-seq rdr)))
```

The map is also lazy so you don't need to consume the entire file in case you would use it on a huge file at some point.

Comment: This seems more clojurist than my version, also +1 for lack of complex regex. :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is quite hacky, but it's what you need...

```
(defn solution [input]
    (let [index-of-key (clojure.string/index-of input "GIT BRANCH")
          next-newline (clojure.string/index-of (subs input index-of-key) "\n")]
  (clojure.string/trim (subs input (+ (count "GIT BRANCH   : ") index-of-key) 
                    (+ index-of-key next-newline)))))
```

`index-of-key` is where `GIT BRANCH` starts on the string. `next-newline` is the first newline after `GIT BRANCH`, so it's the end of our line of interest (we don't look further).
Knowing those two values we find the substring of the input that starts at the end of `GIT BRANCH   :` and ends at the first newline after that.

Examples:

```
user> (def input "TAG A    : HELLO 
       DATE START   : Tue Oct 25 09:51:49 EDT 2015 
       GIT BRANCH   : master 
       GIT COMMIT   : fecb1b53ec8fffffffffffffffffffff09523c42")
#'user/input
user> (solution input)
"master"


user> (def input "TAG A    : HELLO 
       DATE START   : Tue Oct 25 09:51:49 EDT 2015 
       GIT BRANCH   : my-other-branch
       GIT COMMIT   : fecb1b53ec8fffffffffffffffffffff09523c42")
#'user/input
user> (solution input)
"my-other-branch"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. Your solution works. However, I was trying to achieve this in different way but facing issue     `(defn git_branch
  "Returns the GIT branch."
  []
  (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "test.txt")]
    (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
       (let [[fir sec] (clojure.string/split line #":\s+")]
         (if (= fir "GIT BRANCH   ")
           (sec)
           )))))`   Basically I am missing something while returning from this function. My intention is if I call the function git_branch from another function then it should return the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use regex to handle this problem.

```
(def ff "TAG A    : HELLO 
         DATE START   : Tue Oct 25 09:51:49 EDT 2015 
         GIT BRANCH   : master 
         GIT COMMIT   : fecb1b53ec8fffffffffffffffffffff09523c42")



(second (re-find  #"GIT BRANCH\s*:\s*(\w+)\n" ff))
```